# Warning: class implemented in both SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am getting the following error when running my app:

> objc[59714]: Class Message is implemented in both /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME and /Users/aditya15417/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/4EFD7570-AD87-48E8-8606-1D5633F65AD9/CTest.app/CTest. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Why is this? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a class named Message? Change its name, or stop using the MIME framework.

Objective-C doesn't have namespaces like C++ does, so name collisions are possible. This is why Apple prefixes most of its class and function names with two letters, like "NS..." and "CG...". I think the Cocoa coding guidelines recommend that you do the same (using your own prefix, of course).

Comment: Yes I do have a class named Message. What's weird is that I didn't have this warning/error before. I added ShareKit to my project and this occurs.